# Suppose a surface contains a straight line. How can I prove that all the points on this line have non-positive Gaussian curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Suppose a surface contains a straight line. How can I prove that all the points on this line have Gaussian curvature $K_P\leq0$?

Comment: What have you tried? Here's an intuitive starting point: if the Gaussian curvature is positive at a point, then (in some small region) the surface will stay on one side of an "osculating sphere" contacting it at that point, and thus cannot contain a line segment through that point.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: What is the normal curvature at $P$ in the direction of the line? What do you conclude about the two principal curvatures at $P$?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I still don't get it...

Comment: Perhaps you need to tell us more about what you know. What is the definition of Gaussian curvature? What is normal curvature in a certain direction? If you don't know these, perhaps checking your textbook would help.

Comment: I think the normal curvature should be zero along the curve. But then how can I associate it with the principal curvatures?

Comment: There are two ways of thinking about this. Among all possible normal curvatures, how do you recognize the principal curvatures? Alternatively, do you know Euler's formula for normal curvature?

Comment: I know that they are the maximum and minimum curvatures of the various normal slices. But how is it related to the normal curvature? (I don't know Euler's formula...)

Comment: If $0$ is one of the normal curvatures, what does that tell you about the maximum and minimum?

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you're satisfied with our answer, please accept my answer so that this question will go off the unanswered list. :)